# single and mutivariable concavity.

Tags: calculus

Let $f$  be a real-valued function defined on the convex subset $D$ of $\mathbf{R}^n$. Then $f$ is (strictly) concave if and only if for every $x\in D$ and every non-zero $z\in\mathbf{R}^n$, the function $g(t)=f(x+tz)$  is (strictly) concave on $\{t\in\mathbf{R}:x+tz\in D \}$.

I'm not sure how to prove the necessity condition of the above theorem (i.e. going from the concavity of $g$ to the concavity of $f$). If anyone can lend me a hand it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! Can you clean up the formatting using Mathjax (see FAQ)? Regards

Comment: You should clarify which definition of concavity you are using. According to one on wikipedia, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Concave_function, the theorem you are stating is just the definition of a concave function.

Answer (score 0):

Please check if this is correct:

$$\frac{dg}{dt}=(\nabla f(\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{z}))^T.\mathbf{z},$$ and since g is (strictly) concave, 
$$\frac{d^2g}{dt^2}=\mathbf{z^THz}\leq0~~~\forall \mathbf{z}\in D.$$ where $\mathbf{H}$ is the Hessian of f at $\mathbf{x}+t\mathbf{z}$. Note that the inequality is strict if g is strictly concave.

Since the Hessian is Negative Definite (at least over the domain D), the function f is concave over D.

I have one more way of proving it, but I think this is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Just a small note: Proving necessity in this case actually means proving that g is concave whenever f is concave. What you have asked in parentheses is a sufficiency condition.